# switching jpanels with menuItem inside Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to know how can I switch JPanels inside my main JFrame, I have tried this code but when I click the menu item it changes then I click other menu item and does not change, I click the menu Item I clicked first and it changes ....is there other way I can easily switch jpanels? do not show me the cardLayout crap because it doesn't work with what i need and it seems that every answer on google involves that demo, anyway if there is a simple way of doing things I appreciate it if someone helps me point in the right direction thanks.

```
menuItem.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainPane.remove(getContentPane());
            mainPane.add(cdPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            mainPane.validate();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are two ways

1. remove (`JFrame.getContentPane.removeAll()`) and add `JPanel` to `JFrame`, required to call `JFrame.(re)validate` and `JFrame.repaint` after all changes to already visible Swing GUI is done, once time, last code lines
2. (better, correct, proper of ways) use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), code example in official Oracle tutorial, a few good, some excelent examples here

Comment: number one was useful thanks I also had a Jlabel on the JFrame when I first load up the app now when I change jpanels it goes away I am guessing because of the removeAll() is there a way to just leave it there? i have the jlabel as 'mainPane.add(lblWelcome, BorderLayout.SOUTH);' I will keep working on it thanks(:

Comment: be sure that you'll use JFrame.getContentPane.removeAll(), otherwise you can in troubles,

Comment: since JFrame is declared outside of the class I am using I just use getContentPane() by itself and it seems to work

Comment: right ............, even I'd be to declare JFrame as variable, not good idea to hunting for JFrame

Answer (score 0):

Edited Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO code application logic here

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize( 300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();
    panelOne.setBackground( Color.red );

    JPanel panelTwo = new JPanel();
    panelTwo.setBackground(Color.blue);

    frame.setContentPane( panelOne );
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //This delay is just here so you can see the transition
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep( 1000 );
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException ie )
    {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    panelTwo.setSize( frame.getContentPane().getSize() );
    frame.setContentPane( panelTwo );

}
```

---

I would like to point out that there is a class called JTabbedPane.  It might not be what you're looking for, but it's essentially one pane, with multiple tabs on it that a user can click and switch views.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html

Comment: thanks for the links i will take a look at that, the code as you wrote it does not work for me, if I do it like that it will stay in the first jpanel I assign to it

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I tested it out and noted that the previous code would only show the second content pane when you resized the JFrame.  Tried repainting, then found out that the content pane was getting set with size zero.  I've updated the code to address that.